# Решите задачу на Python

Tags: python

Данная лента.  Определите длину найбильшпои подстроки, которая складасться тлько из маленьких латинских букв.  Входные данные Во входном файле записана строка.  Длина строчки не превышает 255 символов.  Выходные данные В выходной файл выведите одно число-длину искомого подстроки.

Comment: А вы как оплачивать работу собираетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вам помогали с решением на StackOverflow, нужно прикладывать своё решение, иначе шанс получить помощь достаточно низкий.

```py
import re

s = input()
d = re.split(r'[^a-z]+', s)

print(max(len(k) for k in d))
```

Результат

```
fjiJFkjKFkJKFjKJfkfkjfkJFKjkfknkfJFkjFKKFjkJFKjF
7
```

И исключительно риторический вопрос: зачем просить решить учебную задачу за вас? Для чего вообще брать учебные задачи по программированию, если программирование интересует вас ровно настолько, чтобы просить кого-то заниматься им вместо вас?

Comment: Квадратные скобки лишние. И str там зачем?

Comment: никогда не понимал, зачем вы помогаете таким участникам?)

Comment: @finally руку набиваю на задачах разного плана) Задачи беру практически все, а если уже есть рабочий код - просто в мусорку выбрасывать жалко ;)